# Why does the newest Angular CLI have a corrupted packages?

Tags: node.js, angular6

I installed the latest Node and Angular on Windows 10

```
npm install npm@latest -g 
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

But when I try to start a project `ng new new-project` I get the following error

```
    npm WARN tarball tarball data for @angular/compiler@^6.1.0 (sha512-TY6axB1c7VvYXf+ebFDq3Ej+edgii3CDxew8HnyTFAWeDF2Gh8io1vTYwtdyDka6U53ASaheM1HpiUjzvYH0jQ==) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time. 
    npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\admin\Desktop\...\node_modules\.staging\@angular\common-6be83a81\locales\si.js'
    ...

    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-10-08T01_01_48_404Z-debug.log
    Package install failed, see above.
```

---

I tried to uninstall Node.js and Angular CLI completely and then reinstall again

```
 npm install npm@latest -g 
 npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

But still the same error ..... So I googled this issue. It seems like some people had it too, but then it magically disappeared for some people.

**How to fix this?**

Comment: I'm also having this problem, but with @angular/compiler@~7.2.0

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the same problem with `node 12.13.0` and `npm 6.13.0`

```
npm WARN tarball tarball data for @angular/compiler@^7.2.11 (sha512-5yb4NcLk8GuXkYf7Dcor4XkGueYp4dgihzDmMjYDUrV0NPhubKlr+SwGtLOtzgRBWJ1I2bO0S3zwa0q0OgIPOw==) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.
```

For me the problem was `npm`. After upgrading npm to the newest version with `npm i -g npm@latest` the problem vanished. So it seems to be a problem with npm itself and not the `Angular/CLI`.

Comment: Finally I got it solved by your answer I can't thank you enough :)

Comment: Thanks. this is very helpful.

Answer (score 13):

I was getting the same below error when attempting to a create new project using `ng new` command.

> npm WARN tarball tarball data for @angular/compiler@~7.2.0
>   (sha512-5yb4NcLk8GuXkYf7Dcor4XkGueYp4dgihzDmMjYDUrV0NPhubKlr+SwGtLOtzgRBWJ1I2bO0S3zwa0q0OgIPOw==)
>   seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.

I tried many things but ***what did not worked*** and ***what finally worked*** for me I have listed below. My working node version is 12.2.0 and npm version is 6.9.0 (i.e. latest version).

**What did not worked:**

1. Downgraded node js to other lower versions (tried many version)
2. Deleted `package-lock.json` file from project and executed `npm install`
3. Executed `npm install --registry https://registry.cnpmjs.org` instead of `npm install`
4. Deleted `npm` and `npm-cache` folders from `AppData\Roaming` and then again installed node js
5. Deleted `node_modules` folder, executed `npm update` and then executed `npm install`
6. Executed `npm cache clean --force` and then executed `npm install`
7. Reinstalled `@angular/cli`
8. Checked for any firewall / antivirus (in my case it was disabled)
9. Opened node command prompt as an administrator
10. Checked user permissions for the project folder

**Finally what worked is:**

Installed the component for which it was giving error. `npm install -global @angular/compiler`

Answer (score 1):

upgrade your NPM version use this command i -g npm@latest  it works like magic